# How can I list all branches with dates and hashes?

Tags: git

How do I get a list of all branches with names, dates and hashes?

I can get a list with the names and dates by

```
git branch -r --format='%(refname:short) %(committerdate:short)'
```

What can I add to the command to include the commit hashes?

Adding `%H` does not work, I already tried it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to `git help git-for-each-ref` (to which `git help branch` refers you), you are looking for `objectname`:

> ```
> objectname
>     The object name (aka SHA-1). For a non-ambiguous abbreviation of
>     the object name append :short. For an abbreviation of the object
>     name with desired length append :short=<length>, where the minimum
>     length is MINIMUM_ABBREV. The length may be exceeded to ensure
>     unique object names.
> ```